# VBA put literal value of string into an excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, string

Excel 2010
Is there a way to put the literal contents of a string variable into an excel cell?

I can achieve what I want to do with this *hard code*, but this code is deep inside nested subroutines. I want to *soft code* this, so that the *contents* of Formula_wanted is inserted in the cell. Here's the code that puts the *value* of the formula in the cell.

```
   If modifier1 = "ILMROS " Then
          Range("M4").Select
          ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Sales Total"
          Range("M5").Select
          ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[@701]+[@707]+[@708]+[@709]+[@712]"
```

The problem with this is that the categories change all the time. They are read from 1 table on the input sheet. If I could make it so that only this input table needed to be altered when categories change, no one would have to dig through the code to find the resulting problem.

I can get VBA to create the string that I want inside a variable, but, trying everything below, I canNOT get it to put the string *from* the variable into cell "M5." Per the rules of OS, I've included everything I've tried with the error received. THANK YOU for any help you can give.

```
   Dim Formula_wanted as string (also tried Dim as Variant, same results)

    Formula_wanted = "=[@"
              For x = 1 To UBound(ILMROS) - 1
                  Formula_wanted = Formula_wanted & ILMROS(x) & "]+[@"
              Next x
      Formula_wanted = Formula_wanted & ILMROS(UBound(ILMROS)) & "]"

  MsgBox "my formula is:  " & Formula_wanted

   'shows this in msgbox: my formula is: = "=[@701]+[@707]+[@708]+[@709]+[@712]"

   '@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

   These all failed:
  Range("Y5").Text = Formula_wanted
     ' error 424
  Range("Y5").Value = Formula_wanted
       error 1004
  Range("y5").Formula = Formula_wanted
      'error 1004
  Range("Y5").FormulaR1C1 = Formula_wanted
      error 1004
  Cells(4, 24).Select
     error 424
  ActiveCell.Text = Formula_wanted
    'error 424

  Set Ob = Range("Y5") ' Ob dim as "object"
    Ob.Value = Formula_wanted
      '1004
 Ob.Text = Formula_wanted
      '1004
  Cells(4, 24).Text = Formula_wanted
      '1004

  ActiveCell.Text = Formula_wanted
         '1004    
  Range("Y5").FormulaLocal = Formula_wanted
      'error 1004

  End Sub
```

Comment: Can you manually enter that formula into a cell without any errors?  Eg `Debug.Print Formula_wanted` and copy it from the Immediate pane.

Comment: Are you trying to insert that formula into a cell which is outside of the referenced table?  That won't work.

Comment: What about `Range("Y5").Value = "'" & Formula_wanted`

Comment: HI Tim! I have used so much of your stuff! Thanks for your help. Yes, one could manually enter the formula. I can also hard code the VBA to put the *answer* of the formula in the cell. But there are 18 spreadsheets, 27 categories, and 6 salesmen. So the manual entry becomes burdensome. Batman - I wondered about that and will try it out!

Comment: BruceWayne - thanks for the suggestion. Your code *does* put the variable string in the cell! However, it puts it as a string (the carriage control character ' does that). That's great to know; unfortunately I was hoping I could get the text into the cell as a formula itself. IE: it puts '=[@701]+[@707]... into the cell, but now the formula won't "do" anything. I think I'll have to stick with ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[@701]+[@707... hard coded for now, making a note in the input data form that one has to find this code in the program and change it when changes to categories are made.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your formula is trying to do, but I don't have enough reputation to comment.  By setting a formula to "=[@701]+[@707]+[@708]+[@709]+[@712]" it looks like you are trying to add values from table columns named 701, 707 etc.

If this is what you are doing then either:

a) you referencing a column that doesn't exist in the table; or
b) "Y5" is not in the table.

If it's a), then correct the column names.  If it's b) then change your formula to

"=Table1[@701]+Table1[@707]+Table1[@708]+Table1[@709]+Table1[@712]"

If you're trying to do something else such as reference a specific row in the table, then you may need to completely rethink and look at using ListObject.  I've found this link very helpful in the past.

[List Object helpful reference](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables)

To clarify further, the formula value in your string variable appears to be invalid.

Example with String variable that works

```
Dim validFormulaString As String
validFormulaString = "=1+2"
Range("A1").Formula = validFormulaString
```

Example with String variable that does not work as the resulting formula is not valid

```
Dim invalidFormulaString As String
invalidFormulaString = "=1$2"
Range("A1").Formula = invalidFormulaString
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for looking and answering. To clarify: correct - the formula adds values from a table. Getting the value into the cell isn't the issue. It can be accomplished with the "hard coded" solution in my question. What I need to do is get the *contents* of the string variable into the cell.

Comment: Hey, no problem.  I have added some more info to my answer that hopefully explains what I was trying to say.  Essentially I think the formula in the string variable is invalid.  Enter my code into a blank workbook and you will see you get a 1004 error in the 2nd one.